# File Manager / Assets problem

Tags: assets, file-uploads, file-manager

I just moved a site from my dev hosting to my client's hosting. 
Every path has been updated correctly. However, all files on Assets or the File manager are not showing on the front end.

When I click "update indexes" on Assets, I get this message:

There are some entries in the database that are out of date - please select the ones that you want to delete below

In addition, I can't upload new files.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance,

Santiago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely a permissions issue if your paths are correct. As Brian said, upload folders should be 777. Also the files inside should have group permissions so PHP can read/edit them.

Another issue I had recently was forgetting to set the cache folder to 777. I'm guessing Assets use this as a temp area to generate thumbs.

Answer (score 0):

Does the folder have the right permissions 777?

Answer (score 0):

Folder permissions were indeed wrong, but it wasn't the only problem. The server path provided by the hosting documentation - and the one detected by the Reelocate addon - were different than $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. I used the latter and the file manager started to work.

I still have problems with Assets but I'm looking into it with P&T.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've had this before - Select the ones to delete. I take it you are using v2.x?

The short of it is, it is safe to 'delete' images. It doesn't actually delete the images. Not 100% sure what it is doing to be honest. But you can rest assured that they are not being deleted.

There is big issue using Assets and dev/live sites. The index gets mixed up a fair bit. If you pull the site down to dev at a later stage, you'll probably run int o this again - Or on the dev site the images are missing. Its a real pain - Not 'Painless' file management as P&T claim. Good addon on though.